# Organisation or organisational skills

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-request, grammaticality, adjectives

Is it more correct or appropriate to say:

"I have strong ***organisation*** skills" OR "I have strong ***organisational*** skills"?

Comment: "organizational skills" works better.

Comment: @Gustavson Seems you are contradicting with Jeremy's answer....or at least too early to judge. The OP's statement needs more context.

Comment: @KentaroTomono In a contextual vacuum, "I have strong organizational skills" sounds much more likely. By the way, I don't need to agree with others' opinions. I just give mine.

Comment: @Gustavson "I have strong organization skills" also sounds nooice^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Organisation skills' might be interpreted as skills to work the particular organisation in which the person concerned operates. They would be an outstanding practitioner of the internal politics of that organisation.

By contrast, 'organisational skills' are the skills needed to organise something: a school sports day, or the D-day invasion of France in  1944.

So, both terms are grammatically correct, but they mean quite different things.

Comment: You might want to edit where it says "skills to work the particular organisation". It seems you have omitted the preposition *for* or *with* or *at/in*.

Comment: @Gustavson Good point. It probably was a typo. But actually, looking at it again, 'working the organisation' better summarises what I mean than 'for, with or at/in.' All of those prepositions describe an 'organisation man' - a person taken over by his devotion to the organisation - I was trying to refer to the opposite: a person who uses the organisation to further personal objectives.